# Valor não se encaixa dentro da caixa de texto

Tags: php, html

Olá, tudo bem pessoal ? Então, estou com um problema chato, fiz uma função que retorna dados de um certo campo da tabela, para assim inserir-o dentro da caixa de texto de um formulário; Mas, o valor retornado do campo aparece em cima da caixa de texto, não dentro do atributo value="". Estou apenas utilizando HTML e PHP para a construção do algoritmo e, pretendo não utilizar javascript por enquanto. Caso alguém responda, agradeço muuuito sua ajuda, pois não estou conseguindo resolver tal problema.

```
      //////////////// Editar ///////////////////////
  function select($id)
  {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE id = $id");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row_user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $row_user['usuario'];
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (isset($_GET['id']) and $_GET['acao'] == 'editar' and $_GET['campo'] == 'usuario')
  {
    echo ('
      <form method=post>
        <input type=text name=edit_usr value='.select($_GET['id']).'><br>
        <input type=submit name=edit_envia value=Editar>
      </form>

    ');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou trocar o `echo $row_user['usuario'];` por `return $row_user['usuario'];`?

Comment: Não, vou tentar agora

Comment: Eiiita kkkk, foi perfeitamente mano! Brigadão ae, mesmo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está dando um `echo` na função quando deveria retornar o valor com um `return`.

Troque o `echo $row_user['usuario'];` por `return $row_user['usuario'];`.

Comment: Opa mano funcionou, é que pensei que dando o return, a função não iria me retornar nenhum output, e assim digo um print na tela, ai mandei um echo direto, mas, pelo visto estava errado. Valeu de novo mano!

Comment: Ho fera, veja isso, descobri a causa mas não sei nada a respeito, veja meus comentarios nesse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324325/como-colocar-link-em-imagens-com-div

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo cara, tô meio sem condição de analisar com frieza a questão agora... mas deixa esfriar a cabeça que vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Sem stress, e se vc se interessar.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo claro meu amigo... me interesso sim... vou dar uma olhada